# Upgrading php binaries installed by Apple

Tags: php, macos, osx-yosemite

I am on Yosemite and I want to upgrade my PHP version (which comes with OSX by default). Right now I am on PHP 5.5.27 and I want to upgrade to PHP 5.6... So, by doing something like this:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6
```

the current binaries wont be overwritten... From the [docs](http://php-osx.liip.ch/):

> php-osx doesn't overwrite the php binaries installed by Apple, but
>   installs everything in /usr/local/php5. The new php binary is
>   therefore in /usr/local/php5/bin/php.
>
> You can also adjust your PATH do include that directory, eg. write
>   into your ~/.profile file the following
>
> export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH

But how would I just upgrade the current php installation ?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) "The missing package manager for OS X".

you can then install php56 with brew

```
brew install php56
```

Comment: So the Homebrew will overwrite the current installation unlike the example above?

Comment: no. it will create a folder where it keeps all apps you install via brew. you will then have to edit your config files.

Comment: why do you want to override the preinstalled version?

Comment: Well, I am able to do that already without Homebrew. The effect is the same  if you use the example I have provided.

Comment: So my question is not how to install latest PHP version. But rather how to upgrade bundled PHP (if I can call it like that). Why do I want that?  Because I am curious and wonder if there is a regular way to do it ;)

Comment: maybe ask your question at Ask Different

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2824/is-it-possible-to-update-the-preinstalled-versions-of-both-mysql-and-php-in-os-x

Comment: Thanks, will peek into that link.